# How to avoid reload packages when running a shiny interactive document?

Tags: r, shiny

Using rmarkdown::run("mydoc.Rmd", auto_load = FALSE) allow to avoid reload packages and the rendering is faster. Is a similar option to pass into the markdown script.

```r
---
runtime: shiny
auto_reload: false
title: 
output:
  html_document:
    toc: yes
    toc_float: yes
    number_sections: yes
    css: style.css
---
```

it simply doesn't work

Comment: what you got as an error ?

Comment: It does not return an error but it still reload packages